# <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h> file not found in bridging file

Tags: swift, objective-c, bridging-header, cocoalumberjack

I have a workspace with multiple targets and mixed development with SWIFT and Objective-C. After installing CocoaLumberjack with CocoaPods:

```
pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'
```

I can use it my project without any problems. All my targets get compiled except Test target. When I run tests I get "build failed" error within the bridging header file

```
<CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h> file not found
```

at:

```
#import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>
```

Do you have any ideas how to fix the issue? Thanks!

Comment: If you're using Swift, just write `import CocoaLumberjack` at the top of your Swift file.  Don't use a bridging header.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I get now another error: "framework not found CocoaLumberjack for architecture x86_64". Although CocoaLumberjack is not used in my XCTestCase, I tried to write this import in the XCTestCase class, I get "No such module 'CocoaLumberjack'" error. All other targets can be still compiled without any problems.